# Error connection server apache

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this error when I log in mysql database:

```
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Did you use the right password for root user?

Comment: we have set no password for user

Comment: The error message tell me, that you using a password.
How did you install mysql, phpmyadmin? And which OS did you use?

Comment: Are you logging in directly or through php code? If the latter please post your code.

Comment: OS it's ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: i reach login page through a link from gandi's web host

Comment: Have you root access on the server?

Comment: no , we have just root access for phpmyadmin but we don't have root access to the server

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it appears as if the link to log in to phpMyAdmin is provided by your host, and that you have no administrative access to the server. Any password reset instructions would require you to have root access to the server in order to stop and start the MySQL daemon.

This means there's nothing we can do to help you; please ask your host for assistance.